# Getting error when i deploy vue app to heroku

Tags: node.js, vue.js, heroku, web-deployment

I have a vuejs app which set up with vue cli, and i'm trying deploy my app to heroku.

Here's my server :

```
const express = require('express');
const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

const app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/dist/"));
app.get(/.*/ , function(req,res) {
  res.sendfile(__dirname + "/dist/index.html");
});

app.listen(port);

console.log("Server started...");
```

---

- I remove dist from gitignore,
- I aded a start point like "start": "node server.js" in package.json

Here's what i see on console :

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 503 (Service Unavailable) /favicon.ico:1

Here's heroku logs :

2019-12-13T08:55:49.464914+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=followgoals.herokuapp.com request_id=09df33ae-96ab-415a-929b-530fb943318d fwd="37.130.123.179" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2019-12-13T08:55:49.828341+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=followgoals.herokuapp.com request_id=21de7307-502e-4104-a648-8e6b0832a3fe fwd="37.130.123.179" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

So what can i do the fix problem ?

Comment: It looks like your express server is crashing. Does it run fine on your local machine?

Comment: Yes it does, no problem on local.

Comment: How have you deployed the app? Since your `server.js` is pretty short, the only possible issues I can think of are (1) node dependencies (`express`) not installed, or (2) the `/dist/` directory or `/dist/index.html` do not exist.

Comment: Actually i missed that npm does not build index.html file in dist folder and server wait for that as you said, this was problem, but i added index.html file in dist folder with a plug-in, but still app does not work on Heroku also local. I got an error en heroku like that : 

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 503 (Service Unavailable)

Thank for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, worked on local, 503 error on heroku, and I fixed it by going to my db cloud service(mongodb atlas), and changed the white list setting on my cluster from "home" to "anywhere".

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=leNNivaQbDY&t=31s